# Making Authorized Calls to an Google Cloud Endpoints API

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints

My Current Setup

- Google Cloud Endpoints hosted on Google App Engine.

  - Google Echo Tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python)
- Python local server making requests to the echo API.

The echo tutorial is up and running. I can make calls to open endpoints and the one requiring an API key using a python script on my machine. I have not been able to make an authorized API call with a Google ID token. None of the Google examples have worked so far.

From my understanding, the workflow should be

1. Use a key file to authorize the service account to generate a JWT.
2. Use the JWT to generate a Google ID token.

Google Example: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#using_a_google_id_token (Key File)
The code fails. Function get_id_token() return res['id_token'] fails with no id_token in res.

**Has anyone gotten the example to work? Does anyone have an example of making an authorized API call to an Endpoint API with a Google ID token from a service account?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue was generating the JWT and the code that works for me is below. I have yet to find a better way to do this that works. If you know of a better way please submit your answers below or add a comment. The code that generates the Google ID Token from JWT is exactly from Google documentation here (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/clients/service_to_service_google_id_token/main.py)  get_id_token function.

```
def generate_jwt(audience, json_keyfile, service_account_email):
"""Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account.
    https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/clients/google-jwt-client.py
"""

# Note: this sample shows how to manually create the JWT for the purposes
# of showing how the authentication works, but you can use
# google.auth.jwt.Credentials to automatically create the JWT.
#   http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.jwt.html#google.auth.jwt.Credentials

signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file(json_keyfile)

now = int(time.time())
expires = now + 3600  # One hour in seconds

payload = {
    'iat': now,
    'exp': expires,
    'aud': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    # target_audience must match 'audience' in the security configuration in your
    # openapi spec. It can be any string.
    'target_audience': audience,
    'iss': service_account_email
}

jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)

return jwt
```

Comment: I get a 401 Unauthorized when I make a request with this code sample against the https://sample-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo/email

I can't seem to make any authorized calls against this endpoint

Comment: Do you see the following error in the logs? 
Error: VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'
If so, try following the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929871/get-request-resulting-in-verifiedhttpsconnection-object-has-no-attribute-tunne

Comment: No - it was Client ID is not allowed: <my client id>.apps.googleusercontent.com
Which I think means the client ID is actually invalid.
I got it working in the end using a variation of your excellent example!

Comment: do we have for nodejs ?