# GET request resulting in VerifiedHTTPSConnection object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, python-requests

I am using the python requests library to make a HTTP GET requests to an API hosted on GAE. Requests version is `requests==2.20.0` and installed via pip using a virtual environment.

The issue has been reported to be caused by an outdated version of python, I am running the very latest version of python 2 (2.7.15).

Here is the code snipped:

```
endpoint_url = API_URL + "some/endpoint/%s" % some_variable
response = requests.get(url=endpoint_url)
return response.text
```

And here is the stackstace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/flask/app.py", line 2292, in 
wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git-r 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/flask/app.py", line 1815, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/flask/app.py", line 1718, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/flask/app.py", line 1813, in 
full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/flask/app.py", line 1799, in 
dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/main.py", line 83, in login
response = requests.get(url=endpoint_url)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/requests/api.py", line 75, in 
get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/requests/api.py", line 60, in 
request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 
524, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 
637, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 
449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", 
line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", 
line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", 
line 839, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/Users/rhys/Desktop/Projects/git- 
repositories/MitigatingCircumstancesTracker/lib/urllib3/connection.py", line 
304, in connect
if self._tunnel_host:
AttributeError: 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 
'_tunnel_host'
```

Python version from `'python --version' 2.7.15`

requirements.txt:

```
bcrypt==3.1.4
certifi==2018.10.15
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
idna==2.7
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pycparser==2.19
requests==2.20.0
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.24
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `python --version` and `pip freeze`?

Comment: $ python --version = Python 2.7.15 && $ pip freeze = virtualenv==16.0.0

Comment: The only dependency you have installed is virtualenv?

Comment: No I have many other dependencies installed, see the contents of my requirements.txt above.

Comment: Even though those dependencies are in your `requirements.txt`, it doesn't mean they're available in your virtual environment. You need to `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install them.

Comment: I absolutely assure you that they are installed, I am using all other dependencies, the application is running. The only issue is in regards to the requests package. They are installed outside of the env directory using `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Got it. You might want to try removing the `lib` directory and running that command again, to ensure you actually have the latest versions of `requests` and `urllib3`. I can't see how this error would happen unless either of them are out of date, or you're somehow using an older version of Python and not realizing it.

Comment: Did that solve your issue @rhys_stubbs ? I have the same problem without `-t lib`

Comment: @ThibaultLeConte It did not fix the issue, the python version was not at all the problem! **I have continued to install all libraries into the lib directory**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was apparently related to Google App Engine's inability to work with requests in local development environment (with SDK).
[AppEngineAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#appengineadapter) requests_toolbelt is needed. Worked for me after.

Comment: Thx so much @EricR6. That worked perfectly. I just had to add `requests_toolbelt` to my requirements.txt file and `from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine` 
`appengine.monkeypatch()` when I init my app.

Comment: @ThibaultLeConte **This is indeed fixed the problem**, I did wonder whether it was the local environment of GAE that was the problem. This is issue documented somewhere that I missed? Regardless, thanks for this, saved a lot of extra work as I had began using the standard urllib libraries!

Comment: for appengine/python2.7: ```from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine 
appengine.monkeypatch()```

Answer (score 0):

To fix up requests to work with Google App Engine but also allow my application to run outside of GAE, I added the following code:

```
try:
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
    from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
    appengine.monkeypatch()
except ImportError:
    pass
```