# Error when connecting to Firebase from dev_appserver: VerifiedHTTPSConnection object has no attribute _tunnel_host

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am running a service locally that I intend to run in GCP as a service. I'm authenticating to Firebase using a service account json file.

```
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('./firebase-service-account.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/'
})
```

...
    ref.child(msg_id).set(data)

However, when I try to write to Firebase, I see the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute 
'_tunnel_host'
```

I'm going to paste the stacktrace below in case it can provide some additional clarity:

```
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/query.py", line 42, in publish_results
ref.child(msg_id).set(data)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/firebase_admin/db.py", line 262, in set
self._client.request('put', self._add_suffix(), json=value, params='print=silent')
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/firebase_admin/db.py", line 882, in request
return super(_Client, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 84, in request
resp = self._session.request(method, self._base_url + url, **kwargs)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 198, in request
self._auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/auth/credentials.py", line 122, in before_request
self.refresh(request)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 322, in refresh
request, self._token_uri, assertion)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 145, in jwt_grant
response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 106, in _token_endpoint_request
method='POST', url=token_uri, headers=headers, body=body)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 120, in __call__
**kwargs)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/Users/karthig/Documents/coding/nocservice/lib/urllib3/connection.py", line 304, in connect
if self._tunnel_host:
AttributeError: 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'
ERROR    2019-01-03 20:02:00,987 worker.py:45] An error occurred during a request.
ERROR    2019-01-03 20:02:00,988 worker.py:46] 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014215/8016720

Comment: Thanks, John. I just found that and was going to post it. Verified it works as advertised :)

Comment: Post your solution with the new code. This will help others.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered in the comments section of the [answer John posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014215/8016720), but to make it more clear, simply add the following lines where you app gets initialized:

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

That's it. See [here](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#appengineadapter) for more information.