# Google App Engine: AttributeError: 'VerifiedHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to scrape a webpage in google app engine and put the content in a file in a storage bucket. I briefly switched to python 3 on one of the versions and then reverted back to python2 on the following version. It worked before I made the switch to python3.

Not sure if it's because of that, but now my app gives out this error:

[image: error]

I already tried using monkeyfix() functions. They did not work. In app.yaml, runtime is python27.

The snippet of code in question:

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_string, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(source_string)

...

upload_blob('[MY BUCKET NAME HERE]', content, destination_filename)
```

Has anyone here had this problem before? Is it a bug?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029272/error-when-connecting-to-firebase-from-dev-appserver-verifiedhttpsconnection-ob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029272/error-when-connecting-to-firebase-from-dev-appserver-verifiedhttpsconnection-ob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to vendor `requests-toolbelt` your `lib` directory with:

```
$ pip install -t lib requests-toolbelt
```

And then do:

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, don't forget to accept the answer :)